# Prove that the Pell's Equation $x^2 −Dy^2 = 1$ always has a solution where $y$ is a multiple of $41$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation, pell-type-equations

**$D$ is a positive integer that is not a perfect square**

Recently I am taking a introductory number theory course and I met this question right after we learned Pell's equation and Diophantine Approximation. However, I can't see a connection between those 2 topics and this question.

I was trying to assume that $ y = 41k$ where k is an positive integer and substitute it into the equation and I hoped eventually this will simplify to an equation that conforms the form of the Pell's equation which is $x^2-Dy^2=1$. However I did not get any from there.

Also I tried to approach this problem from the Pell's Equation Theorem. Then I found it is impossible to get anything useful from expanding $(x+y{\sqrt D})^k$ plus I cannot determine the smallest solution for it because I don't know the value of D.

Could someone help me on this question? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Help me out.  I'm still a bit of a novice but, you're saying the equation you are trying to solve has a special name.  Did you learn how to solve this "Pell's equation"?  Doesn't $D$ need to not be a perfect square?

Comment: I added the constraint to the question body. The title only allows 150 characters. Sorry about that. I appreciate your time!!

Comment: @Chad : The title really shouldn't be the problem statement.  It should generally describe the problem.  For instance "Constrained solution of several Pell's Equations" or whatever sums up your problem.  The detailed statement should go in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I edited the title. Does it look better now? I condensed some of the words.

Comment: Apparently this can be pretty involved.  You need, firstly, the sequence of convergents from the continued fraction approximation to $\sqrt D$.  That gets you the fundamental solution.  Then there's a recurrence relation to get the infinitely many other solutions.  Good luck.  Some number theory expert might come along and help you out.  I also noticed that this is related to Archimedes' cattle problem.  Reminds of a good book I read years ago:. _Archimedes' Revenge_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n+y_n\sqrt D=(x_1+y_1\sqrt D)^n$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the primitive unit. Since there are only $41^2=1681$ possibilities for $(x_n,y_n)$ $\pmod{41}$ a duplicate must be encountered at some point: $x_n\equiv x_m\pmod{41}$ and $y_n\equiv y_m\pmod{41}$ for some $n>m\ge1$. Then $x_{n-m}=x_nx_m-Dy_ny_m\equiv x_n^2-Dy_n^2\equiv1\pmod{41}$ and $y_{n-m}=-x_ny_m+y_nx_m\equiv-x_ny_n+y_nx_n\equiv0\pmod{41}$.

**EDIT**: As an example let $D=3$ and the first solution to Pell's equation is $x_1+y_1\sqrt D=2+1\sqrt3$. Now let's make a table of values $\pmod{41}$:
$$\begin{array}{r|r|r}n&x_n&y_n\\\hline
1&2&1\\
2&7&4\\
3&26&15\\
4&15&15\\
5&34&4\\
6&39&1\\
7&40&0\\
8&39&40\\
9&34&37\\
10&15&26\\
11&26&26\\
12&7&37\\
13&2&40\\
14&1&0\\
15&2&1\end{array}$$
For example $(2+1\sqrt3)^2=7+4\sqrt3$, $(2+1\sqrt3)^3=26+15\sqrt3$, and $(2+1\sqrt3)^4=97+56\sqrt3$ so $x_4=97\equiv15\pmod{41}$ and $y_4=56\equiv15\pmod{41}$, thus explaining the row $n=4$, $x_n\equiv15$, $y_n\equiv15$. The first duplicate was $x_{15}\equiv x_1\equiv2\pmod{41}$ and $y_{15}\equiv y_1\equiv1\pmod{41}$, so that tells us that $x_{15-1}=x_{14}\equiv1\pmod{41}$ and $y_{15-1}=y_{14}\equiv0\pmod{41}$. Perhaps a bit anticlimactic since we already found $2$ solutions on our way to generating the first duplicate. Indeed $x_{14}^2-3y_{14}^2=50843527^2-3\cdot29354524^2=1$ and $y_{14}=29354524=41\cdot715964$.

**EDIT**: Oh yeah, the last $2$ lines: since $(x_n+y_n\sqrt D)(x_n-y_n\sqrt D)=(x_1+y_1\sqrt D)^n(x_1-y_1\sqrt D)^n=(x_1^2-Dy_1^2)^n=(1)^n=1$ we see that $(x_n+y_n\sqrt D)^{-1}=(x_n-y_n\sqrt D)$ so $(x_{n-m}+y_{n-m}\sqrt D)=(x_n+y_n\sqrt D)(x_m-y_m\sqrt D)=(x_nx_m-Dy_ny_m)+(-x_ny_m+y_nx_m)\sqrt D$

**EDIT** My program that finds the fundamental solution to $x^2-Dy^2=1$ and the first power $n-m$ for which $x_{n-m}\equiv1\pmod{41}$ and $y_{n-m}\equiv0\pmod{41}$

```
program pell
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer(INT64) D
   integer(INT64) sqD, r, s, a, p0, p1, p, q0, q1, q, n
   integer(INT64) m
   write(*,'(a)') '  D         x_1                  y_1            n-m'
   do D = 1, 100
      sqD = int(sqrt(D+0.5D0),INT64)
      if(sqD**2==D) cycle
      r = 0
      s = 1
      p0 = 0
      p1 = 1
      q0 = 1
      q1 = 0
      do n = 1, 200
         a = (sqD+r)/s
         p = a*p1+p0
         p0 = p1
         p1 = p
         q = a*q1+q0
         q0 = q1
         q1 = q
         r = a*s-r
         s = (D-r**2)/s
         if(mod(n,2) == 0 .AND. s == 1) then
            write(*,'(i4,1x,i17,1x,i18)',advance='no') D,p,q
            p0 = mod(p,41)
            q0 = mod(q,41)
            p1 = 1
            q1 = 0
            do m = 1, 1000000
               p = p1*p0+D*q1*q0
               q = p1*q0+q1*p0
               p1 = mod(p,41)
               q1 = mod(q,41)
               if(p1 == 1 .AND. q1 ==0) then
                  write(*,'(1x,i4)') m
                  exit
               end if
            end do
            exit
         end if
      end do
   end do
end program pell
```

And its output:

```
  D         x_1                  y_1            n-m
   2                 3                  2    5
   3                 2                  1   14
   5                 9                  4   20
   6                 5                  2   42
   7                 8                  3   21
   8                 3                  1    5
  10                19                  6   20
  11                10                  3   42
  12                 7                  2    7
  13               649                180   14
  14                15                  4    7
  15                 4                  1   21
  17                33                  8   42
  18                17                  4    5
  19               170                 39   42
  20                 9                  2   20
  21                55                 12   40
  22               197                 42   42
  23                24                  5   10
  24                 5                  1   42
  26                51                 10   42
  27                26                  5   14
  28               127                 24   21
  29              9801               1820   14
  30                11                  2   42
  31              1520                273    5
  32                17                  3    5
  33                23                  4   40
  34                35                  6   21
  35                 6                  1   42
  37                73                 12   20
  38                37                  6   42
  39                25                  4   40
  40                19                  3   20
  41              2049                320   82
  42                13                  2   40
  43              3482                531   10
  44               199                 30   21
  45               161                 24   10
  46             24335               3588   20
  47                48                  7    7
  48                 7                  1    7
  50                99                 14    5
  51                50                  7   20
  52               649                 90   14
  53             66249               9100   14
  54               485                 66   14
  55                89                 12    7
  56                15                  2    7
  57               151                 20   40
  58             19603               2574   42
  59               530                 69   10
  60                31                  4   21
  61        1766319049          226153980    5
  62                63                  8   20
  63                 8                  1   21
  65               129                 16   42
  66                65                  8   10
  67             48842               5967   42
  68                33                  4   42
  69              7775                936   14
  70               251                 30   42
  71              3480                413   21
  72                17                  2    5
  73           2281249             267000   20
  74              3699                430   20
  75                26                  3   14
  76             57799               6630   21
  77               351                 40   40
  78                53                  6    8
  79                80                  9    7
  80                 9                  1   20
  82               163                 18   82
  83                82                  9    4
  84                55                  6   40
  85            285769              30996    2
  86             10405               1122   20
  87                28                  3   40
  88               197                 21   42
  89            500001              53000   42
  90                19                  2   20
  91              1574                165   40
  92              1151                120    5
  93             12151               1260    7
  94           2143295             221064    3
  95                39                  4    7
  96                49                  5   21
  97          62809633            6377352   42
  98                99                 10    5
  99                10                  1   42
```

Comment: Sorry. I understand the sentence "there are only 1681 possibilities." However, I cant follow what is after that. Would you mind showing me that explicitly or have a little bit more explanation? Especially on the last two lines.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation, but why does it guarantee that there will be a duplicate for any value of D? I saw when n = 7, y is also a multiple of 41 but when n = 6, y is not a multiple of 41. I think I did not fully understand this method.

Comment: That's the pigeonhole principle: if you put $1682$ things (pairs $(x_n,y_n)$) in $1681$ boxes (the possible congruence classes $\pmod{41}$), then you have to put at least $2$ things in at least $1$ box. When we made up that table we were guaranteed to hit a duplicate by row $1682$ (actually $1681$ because $(x_n,y_n)\equiv(0,0)\pmod{41}$ is not possible).

Comment: Ok so there must be duplicates because of Pigeon Hole Principle, but why do we know that the row right before the row contains duplicates modulo 41 must have y as multiple of 41 in general? How should I explain that? Since this table is just one observation.

Comment: Well. I didn't actually say that. What I said was that if rows $n$ and $m$ are duplicates and $n>m$ then $y_{n-m}\equiv0\pmod{41}$. But since then $x_{n-m}\equiv1$ and $y_{n-m}\equiv0$ then $x_{n-m+1}\equiv x_{n-m}x_1+Dy_{n-m}y_1\equiv1\cdot x_1+D\cdot0\cdot y_1\equiv x_1$ and $y_{n-m+1}\equiv x_{n-m}y_1+y_{n-m}x_1\equiv1\cdot y_1+0\cdot x_1\equiv y_1$ it does it fact turn out that the first duplicate is between the first row and the row after the one the theorem promises we will find. It turns out that the first duplicate happens no later than row $1641$ and the first $D$ is $D=10$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Scratch what I said about the first duplicate no later than $1641$ -- there was a bug in my program. I will post my corrected program.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 41^2 = 1681  $$

Since $D$ is positive and not a square,  $1681D$ is positive and not a square.

Find a solution for

$$ u^2 - (1681D)v^2 = 1  $$
Then
$$  u^2 - D (41v)^2 = 1   $$

Answer (score 0):

There is an old parametric solution for Pell equation that says, if x, y and D are certain functions of a parameter such as $m$ , there can be infinite solutions"

We rewrite equation as:

$x^2-1=Dy^2$

$1$ is odd and number of terms on LHS is even so one of terms must be odd. Suppose $x^2$ is odd and we have:

$x=2m^2+1$

$(2m^2+1)^2-1=D y^2$

$4m^2(m^2+1)=D.y^2$

So we must have:

$y^2=4m^2$ ⇒ $y=2m$

${D=m^2+1}$

So m can have any value in $\mathbb Z$, incuding all multiple of $41$.

For the smallest solution you can let $m=1$, then we have:

$D=1^2+1=2$

$x=2\times 1^2 +1=3$

$y=2\times 1=2$

If you want y a multiple of $41$, just let $m=41$, then:

$(x, y, D)= (3363, 82, 1682)$

Comment: Why does even number of terms on the LHS implies one of which must be odd?

Comment: I said one term must be odd, it can also be $Dy^2$, simply because $x^2$ and $Dy^2$ must be two consecutive numbers.